# getChildHtml() in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, html, view.phtml

In one of my `.phtml` file I got below line. How can I edit the `ChildHtml` ?

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>
```

Comment: what changes do you want in `getChildHtml` ?

Comment: do you want to get/edit content of `product_additional_data` ?

Comment: @Pawan, Yes, I want to edit content of `product_additional_data`.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Often block will have default templates set in the block. In your example this is the case.

If you look in the file `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Additional` you will see the setting of the template.

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/additional.phtml');
}
```

A great way of finding these template is by setting template hints via the admin,

also you can rename tab and reorder tab here
Create the file `app/frontend/design/{packageName}/{themeName}/layout/local.xml` if it does not exist already.

**Note:** `{packageName}` is most likely "***default***" or "***rwd***", depending on your site setup. `{themeName}` should be a folder you created to use as the theme for your site, which extends the "default" theme.

In that ***local.xml*** file, include the following: (If this file already exists for you, just add the contents within the '**catalog_product_view**' layout handle).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info"> 
            <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.reviews" as="reviews" before="-" template="review/product/view/list.phtml" >
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Reviews</value></action>
            </block>
            <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" after="product.attributes" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Description</value></action>
            </block>
            <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" after="product.reviews" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Additional Information</value></action>
            </block>                                             
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

See the below the re-arrange tabs :

[image: default product page tabs order]

**After :**

[image: re-arrange product tabs on view page]

and after edit this file

Comment: Thanks @Rakesh Donga for your reply. I enabled Template path hints.I am not getting `catalog/product/view/additional.phtml` file. Below is my folder structure. 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAIi0.png

Comment: you can override base file in your theme after you can try `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/additional.phtml`

Comment: Thanks @Rakesh Donga. Actually I would like to edit these. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyxT9.png. I am getting this code `<?php foreach ($this->getChildHtmlList() as $_html): ?>
    <?php echo $_html ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>`  in this `app/design/frontend/codazon_fastest/default/template/catalog/product/view/additional.phtml` file.  How can I edit them ? Thanks

Comment: means you remove any tab?

Comment: Thanks @Rakesh Donga. I would like to Rename a tab and Reorder a tab. Thanks.

Comment: you can check your theme in catalog.xml and edit this file

Comment: Thanks @Rakesh Donga. I got these line `<block type="catalog/product_view_additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data"/>` in `catalog.xml` file. How can I get the `HTML` file ?

Comment: I  am getting this code `<?php foreach ($this->getChildHtmlList() as $_html): ?> <?php echo $_html ?> <?php endforeach; ?>` in this `app/design/frontend/codazon_fastest/default/template/catalog/product/view/additional.phtml` file. How can I edit them ? Thanks

Comment: check my answer